# Up-to-date hardware compatibility lists

Tags: networking, hardware

I'm looking for an up-to-date list of NIC's compatible with Ubuntu 10.10. One of the PC's here in the office suffered a network hardware failure in the on-motherboard network interface. We've fitted an off-the-shelf PCI NIC from a local PC store, but the machine won't boot with the card installed. It may be a driver issue, but the supplied driver won't compile with the 2.6.35 kernel on that machine. So I'd like to buy a replacement card that will be supported out-of-the-box, but the only HCL I can find is [this wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsWiredNetworkCards), last updated in 2009. We can't find any of the devices on that list on sale locally.

Failing a general list, can anyone suggest a good drop-in NIC that will "just work" with Lucid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [networking section](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/NETWORK) of the component catalogue has officially certified hardware.

- [Component Catalogue](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog)

Answer (score 3):

You can find several sites that have a compatibility list. Some up to date, some not so much. In either case it would be a great idea to merge them all into one updated list that reflects the compatibility of the stable release of the kernel + changes for each popular distro.

http://www.linux-drivers.org/

I recommend the following to use as a compatibility finder:

http://hardware4linux.info - User added compatibility information

http://www.sane-project.org/sane-supported-devices.html - Scanner compatibility

http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Main - Sound compatibility

http://openbenchmarking.org/ - Phoronix test site. shows Pcs tested and more.

But you can find the rest and the first link I posted.