# How to determine if new hardware is compatible?

Tags: hardware, compatibility

I am looking to purchase a new laptop but do not want to run Windows. In order to utilize both the new laptop and Ubuntu to their fullest, I want to verify that the hardware is fully compatable with the OS.

Is there a compatability matrix available that can be used to verify this? Does the hardware need to support open drivers or something similar?

Comment: Related Post: [Up-to-date hardware compatibility lists](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33969/up-to-date-hardware-compatibility-lists?rq=1)

Comment: Have a look, [system 76](https://www.system76.com/laptops/model/bonx7)

Comment: I think shopping recs are off topic here, but most Linux folks I know still swear by Lenovo ThinkPads for "just works" laptops. I had an x301 that was awesome until the fan choked. I just set up an X1 Carbon, love that too.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

[Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/)